# Change depth level of nested for each loop during runtime

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to be able to iterate over the same collection to a specified depth.
For example:

```
function (depth){
    var arr = [1,2,3];

    //depth = 1

    arr.forEach(function(val) { 
        func(val); 
    });


    // depth = 2

    arr.forEach(function (val) { 
            arr.forEach( function (val2) { 
                func(val, val2); 
            });
    });

    //and so on

}
```

is there a way to do this in JS?

Comment: This called recursion; you should define `func` so it calls itself when it encounters another level within the array, and take a look at this comment for suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

you write a function that keeps track of your location and removes one till you hit zero.

```
function goDeep (depth, array, func) {
  if ( depth && array && array.length ) {
    array.forEach(function (element) {
      goDeep(depth-1, element, func)
    });
  } else {
     func(array)
  }
}
```